# Java: Retrieve results from Persistence Query Language using List

Tags: java, list, persistence

Im querying a database using JPQL but I cannot retrieve the 'Report' table's rows using List. This is a section of my code:

```
...
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT r.title, r.company FROM Report as r");
     List<Report> itemList = query.getResultList();
     for (Report item : itemList)
     {
        System.out.println("Item: " + item.getCompany());
  }
```

The output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to maps.Report at hello.Test.main(Unknown Source)
```

Java Result: 1

What am I doing wrong? Why I am not allowed to do the casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't select instances of `Report`. It selects two fields: `r.title` and `r.company`. In this case, JPA returns a list of `Object[]`. Each `Object[]` of the list contains two elements: the title and the company.

Use `select r from Report r` to select `Report` instances.

Comment: yup, thanks a lot! I have also found this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1152) in the hibernate-entity manager documentation about scalar results and how to deal with them. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TypedQuery.

```
String sql = "select r from Report r";
TypedQuery<Report> query = em.createQuery(sql, Report.class);
List<Report> reports = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: This won't make Hibernate magically change the tuples it has selected into Report instances.

Comment: It's clear from the code *after* the OP's "createQuery" statement that  the OP does **not** want tuples.

Comment: My point is that what's important is to change the HQL (which is not SQL, BTW), not to create a TypedQuery. His code will be OK even with an untyped query (he'll just have a compiler warning). And given his HQL query, I would guess that the OP wants to select Report instances with only the title and company fields populated, which is not possible.

Comment: The OP calls `getCompany()` on the report objects, thus I assumed the OP wanted the full report objects to be read. If the OP really wants just the two columns, then the OP will need to clarify.